# Unable to retrieve data from website with multiple pages

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I could really use some help regarding a problem I'm facing. I have a project where I'm supposed to fetch the names and prices of some products. I must retrieve data from the first 5 pages of a given category.I'm trying to implement it using R, the rvest package and the SelectorGadget extension to choose the appropriate css selectors. I've written a function to do that:

```
readDataProject2<-function(){
  url<-readline(prompt="Enter url: ")
  nameTags<-readline(prompt="Enter name tags: ")
  priceTags<-readline(prompt="Enter price tags: ")
  itemNames<-read_html(url)%>%html_nodes(nameTags)%>%html_text()
  itemPrices<-read_html(url)%>%html_nodes(priceTags)%>%html_text()
  itemPrices<-itemPrices[-c(1,2)]
  page<-cbind(itemNames,itemPrices)
```

}

and here's the page [anesishome.gr](https://www.anesishome.gr/%CE%B2%CF%81%CE%B5%CF%86%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AC-159#!/). From this specific page I can go to the next etc to fetch a total of...240 products. But even when I provide the url for the next page, [second page](https://www.anesishome.gr/%CE%B2%CF%81%CE%B5%CF%86%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AC-159#!/page-2), I keep getting the data of the first page. Needless to say that choosing the option to present 240 in one single page didn't do any good. Can anybody point me to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi @George, this one is trickier. That page seems to me to be built using some JS framework so the elements are rendered only if an actual browser make the request. This means that `rvest` is not going to work here, at least as intended. Try looking into `RSelenium` to simulate a normal browser behaviour.

Comment: Hi G Gamba, I thought the same, I just hoped to avoid it because I haven't used it so far... Thank you for the response!

Comment: That site prohibits scraping in it's Terms of Service. Please don't encourage others to be unethical.

Comment: I'm sorry,  @hrbrmstr you are right, I even looked for that, but i did not understand a thing in the language

Comment: There is also [Splashr](https://rud.is/b/2017/02/09/diving-into-dynamic-website-content-with-splashr/) now. You can try it with this [site](http://www.techstars.com/companies/), which doesn't prohibit scraping in its Terms of Service.